# Removing new line from links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been given a html document that has links with linebreaks in them (return key). This is messing up the link tracking system we are using. i was thinking of creating a little jQuery script that removes all linebreaks from a href tag. Would this work? . How would i go about targeting the return key new line?

Comment: Any sample code which is causing issues ? Will be difficult to assume many thing..

Comment: Couldn't you just change it server side instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');
    if (href) {
        self.attr('href', href.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''));
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/6csjcrz2/ -  i've tried it locally and it doesn't update the link or return it without the spaces. Not sure what's going on with the JSfiddle, $ is undefined. Odd.

Comment: Weird, i thought i did add it. Not used to the new jsfiddle layout! Thanks! I've slightly amended your code to remove any whitespace too https://jsfiddle.net/y1L1okbt/. i'm not the best with RegEx, does '/n/r' look for a new line?

Comment: @Namenone `[\n\r]` is one of line feed or carriage return.

Comment: @Namenone you can use single regex `/\s/g` it will remove new lines as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to make it easier for myself by having a textarea where i can paste in HTML and have it output without any spaces or line breaks in the href tags. I've gotten halfway but cant seem to find a way to target hrefs inside of a text area. Any ideas anyone? https://jsfiddle.net/7orc6m2g/

Comment: You can convert the textarea string to html using jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/7orc6m2g/2/ and then search for a links.

Comment: Duh! This is what happens when i don't do JS for a few months. Thanks so much! Makes perfect sense now :)